# Get the pixel value of a raster object using Python and ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, raster, spatial-analyst

I used the following code to get the pixel value of specific location of a DEM image (in GRID format):

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
inRaster="C:\\data\\dem"
slop_temp=Slope(inRaster)
print slop_temp[1,1]
```

but got the following error:

> TypeError: 'Raster' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.
and I want to have access to a cell (or cells) by the row and column number(and not by geographic coordinates)

Comment: If it is just a single pixel why not use a single tool - https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/get-cell-value.htm

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/459179/edit) and specify what software (ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro)